# r creating an event table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a datatable as shown below

```
  Event   Time
  0       0
  0       0
  0       0
  0       0
  1       1
  0       7
  0       11
  1       20
  0       21
```

Here, 1 indicates Event = Yes, 0 is Event= No. What I am trying to do is tranform this raw dataset into four columns, time, SampleSize, Event, Non-Event.

```
    time  SampleSize  Event      Non-Event
    0     9           0          4
    1     5           1          0
    7     4           0          1
    11    3           0          1
    20    2           1          0
    21    1           0          1
```

Not sure how to go about doing this. Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated.

Comment: Should `time == 0` have `Non-Event` equal to 4 instead of `Event`?

Comment: @brittenb, you are absolutely correct. I have changed the expected results based on your suggestions.

Comment: How is `SamoleSize` calculated?

Comment: @brittenb, `SampleSize[i+1]  = SampleSize[i] - Event[i] + Non-Event[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please my answer using base R:

```
# raw data
d1 <- data.frame(Event = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0), 
                 Time = c(0,0,0,0,1,7,11,20,21))

d2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(d1$Time, d1$Event))
colnames(d2) <- c("Non-Event", "Event")
times <- as.numeric(rownames(d2))
d3 <- cbind(time = times, 
            SampleSize = sapply(times, function(x){ 
              nrow(d1) - min(which(x == d1$Time)) + 1
              }),
            d2)
rownames(d3) <- NULL
d3
#  time SampleSize Non-Event Event
#1    0          9         4     0
#2    1          5         0     1
#3    7          4         1     0
#4   11          3         1     0
#5   20          2         0     1
#6   21          1         1     0
```

Comment: thanks for the suggested approach however i am seeing -inf values when calculating SampleSize in come cases. Can I request a different approach if it is possible

Comment: I not really sure what sample size is to be honest. You didn’t explain it - even though I do see that formula comment